# Multiple axios calls after login that needs to wait each other, before redirecting user to dashboard on Vue.js [Timing issue]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

Login.vue

```
methods: {
  loginUser() {
    this.$store.dispatch("auth/loginUser", { email: this.email, password: this.password })
    .then(() => {
      // Login ok, redirect user to dashboard
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // Show error
    })
  }
}
```

Auth.js

```
actions: {
  async loginUser ({dispatch}, {email, password}) {
      return axios.post(url, {email, password})
        .then(response => {
          dispatch('otherAction');
        })
        .catch(response => {
      })
  },
  async otherAction ({ dispatch, commit }) {
    // Do other stuff
  }
}
```

I use Vuex and actions to perform API calls. I need to wait **otherAction** dispatch before redirecting user to dashboard.
The problem is I can not use await in the then call. axios.post in the auth.js basically checks credentials of the user. After that I need to do a few more call to get all necessary data to show. Currently, user is redirected to dashboard, but I see errors on the dashboard because it doesn't wait until the '*get extra data of a user*' call is completed to get the needed data. The thing is timing issue.

My way of thinking may be completely wrong. How can I make it work?

Comment: is the 'extra data' being returned eventually? just too late? or not at all?

Comment: It's returning, but sometimes a bit late. The login call may be also late depending on the network. I just don't want to make sure that it always runs by order.

Comment: create ```data.user``` to store the response from loginUser(). Then create a ```watch { user(u) { " dispatch otherAction " } }``` then store the response from other action in something like ```data.userDetails```, then if you need to, ```watch { userDetails(d) { this.$emit('login', { user: this.user, details: this.userDetails } }```

Comment: ah, the ```emit``` probably doesn't fit the vuex construct. But the general idea is to create state data to house api response data, then react only when that data is watched

Answer (score 0):

Make another action that dispatches all the other actions and stores the returned promises in an array then use Promise.all()

Comment: I tried it, but the thing is there is a relationship between the first call and second call. Promise.all() is suitable for doing batch calls but has no ordering ability.